# IoGetDeviceObjectPointer() fails with no return status

Tags: windows, winapi, driver

This is my code:

```
UNICODE_STRING  symbol;     
WCHAR ntNameBuffer[128];
swprintf(ntNameBuffer, L"\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition1");

RtlInitUnicodeString(&symbol, ntNameBuffer);
KdPrint(("OSNVss:symbol is %ws\n",symbol.Buffer));

status = IoGetDeviceObjectPointer(&symbol,                                                  
             FILE_READ_DATA,
             &pDiskFileObject,
             &pDiskDeviceObject);
```

My driver is next-lower-level of `\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition1`.

When I call `IoGetDeviceObjectPointer` it will fail and no status returns and it not continue do remaining code.

When I use windbg debug this, it will break with a `intelpm.sys`;

If I change the objectname to `"\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition2"` (the partition2 is really existing), it will success call

If I change objectname to `"\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition3"`, (the partition3 is not existing), it failed and return status = `0xc0000034`, mean objectname is not existing.

Does anybody know why when I use object `"\\Device\\Harddisk1\\Partition1"` it fails and no return status? thanks very much!

Comment: What does "no status return" mean? Would you please elaborate! The function doesn't even return? Because it will most certainly leave you a nice return code in the EAX register. And returning `0` is perfectly fine here, as it means success (`STATUS_SUCCESS`). So what do you mean by that? If you would be handing down the IRP I could imagine some reasons, but this just sounds too spacey ...

Comment: Yes ,the functin doesn't even return,the code after IoGetDeviceObjectPointer will not do; even I call the function funA which I call the IoGetDeviceObjectPointer again, it can't enter funA

Comment: why don't you edit your question then to add this information? ;) ... the fact that it doesn't return sound like something is blocking the call (i.e. it's becoming synchronous). Have you tried with another access mask?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost: what are you trying to achieve and what driver model are you using? What bitness, what OS versions are targeted and on which OS version does it fail? Furthermore: you are at the correct IRQL for the call *and* is running inside a *system thread*, right? From which of your driver's entry points (`IRP_MJ_*`, `DriverEntry` ...) are you calling this code?

Anyway, was re-reading the docs on this function. Noting in particular the part:

> The **IoGetDeviceObjectPointer** routine returns a pointer *to the top object in the named device object's stack* and a pointer to the
>   corresponding file object, if the requested access to the objects can
>   be granted.

and:

> **IoGetDeviceObjectPointer** establishes a "connection" between the caller
>   and the next-lower-level driver. A successful caller can use the
>   returned device object pointer to initialize its own device objects.
>   It can also be used as as an argument to IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack,
>   IoCallDriver, and any routine that creates IRPs for lower drivers. The
>   returned pointer is a required argument to IoCallDriver.

You don't say, but if you are doing this on a 32bit system, it may be worthwhile tracking down what's going on with [IrpTracker](http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=199). However, my guess is that said "connection" or rather the request for it gets somehow swallowed by the next-lower-level driver or so.

It is also hard to say what kind of driver you are writing here (and yes, this can be important).

Try not just breaking at a particular point before or after the fact but rather follow the stack that the IRP would travel downwards in the target device object's stack.

But thinking about it, you probably aren't attached to the stack at all (for whatever reason). Could it be that you actually should be using **IoGetDiskDeviceObject** instead, in order to get the actual underlying device object (at the bottom of the stack) and not a reference to the top-level object attached?

Last but not least: don't forget you can also ask this question over on the [OSR mailing lists](http://www.osronline.com/page.cfm?name=listserver). There are plenty of seasoned professionals there who may have run into the exact same problem (assuming you are doing all of the things correct that I asked about).

Answer (score 0):

thanks everyone , I solve this problem; what cause this problem is it becoming  synchronous; when I
call IoGetDeviceObjectPointer , it will generate an new  Irp IRP_MJ_WRITER which pass though from high level, when this irp reach my driver, my thread which handle IRP is the same thread whilch call IoGetDeviceObjectPointer ,so it become drop-dead halt;